# MySQL select statement from two tables

Tags: mysql, join

A common scenario I imagine, but I can't seem to find the terminology to find this answer...

I have two tables, one referencing the other like so:

```
topics
------------
title
category_id

categories
------------
category_id
category_title
```

How would I write a query to select the title and category_title of a topic, instead of the id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT  title, 
        category_title
FROM    topics t inner join
        categories c    ON t.category_id = c.category_id
```

Have a look at [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html)

Answer (score 2):

The terminology you are looking for is called a join.

`select title,category_title from topics,categories where title.category_id = categories.category_id;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
select t.title, c.category_title from topic t, categories c where t.category_id = c.category_id;
```